# dominated convergence and multiple intregrals

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, pointwise-convergence

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^+$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^+$, such that $f_n(x_1,x_2)\to f(x_1,x_2)$, in order to apply the dominated convergence theorem to obtain
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_n(x_1,x_2)h(y,z)dydzdx_1dx_2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x_1,x_2)h(y,z)dydzdx_1dx_2,
$$
what do I have to verify about the functions in the integrand?

Well, I know I have to verify that $f_n$ is bounded for all $n$ and $(x_1,x_2)$ and the RHS integration must be finite, but is that it? or do I have to verify something else?

Answer (score 2):

DCT applies to integration w.r.t any measure. Your multiple integrals are just integrals w.r.t Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^{4}$. So you need the usual assumption that $|f_n(x_1,x_2)h(y,z)| \leq |\phi (x_1,x_2,y,z)|$ with $|\phi (x_1,x_2,y,z)|$ integrable over $\mathbb R^{4}$.

(Since Lebesgue measure is an infinite measure uniform boundeness of $f_n$'s is not good enough).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you elaborate a little bit more about the comment in brackets?

Comment: @Ludwig In DC T boundedness works only when  you are integrating over a finite interval or  integrating  w.r.t a finite measure. DCT is applicable if the intergand is  dominated by an integrable function .